# I am not getting splash screen in my app, only blank white screen is coming after that second activity is running

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

```
package cppandi.apjquotes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;

public class MainSplashScreen extends Activity {

/** Duration of wait **/
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 5000;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.front);

    /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity
     * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainSplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
            MainSplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            MainSplashScreen.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
}
```

Here is my front.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/front"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cppandi.apjquotes">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainSplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".quotes"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".about"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>

</application>
```

After opened my android app it is showing like white screen for 5 seconds and it is going to next activity "Mainactivity", But my image in front.xml is not displaying.

Comment: why do you need this splash screen?, this will just give five seconds delay in the app, which is not good ,do a splash screen if you have any thing to load before entering in to main app.

Comment: Yeah I have Logo to show in splash screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
app:srcCompat="@mipmap/front"
```

With this:

```
android:src="@mipmap/front"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@mipmap/front" //change this
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

srcCompat attribute is actually defined within AppCompat library.

From documentation:

**app:srcCompat**

> is used for integrating vector drawables into your
>   app.Vector drawables allow you to replace multiple png assets with a
>   single vector graphic, defined in XML. While previously limited to
>   Lollipop and higher devices

**android:src**

> Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.It will display in
>   its original size. No automatic scaling .

Answer (score 0):

**app:srcCompat** is used to support vector drawables. Ensure that you have added **vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true** in your `build.gradle` file

```
android {  
       defaultConfig {  
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
        }  
     }
```

or you can replace it with `android:src=`